# Spanish characters on a (fr_CA) QWERTY keyboard

Tags: keyboard, special-characters, shortcut-keys

I've just spent about half an hour reading forums and such, so in short of finding a working solution, I ask this here.

All solutions found so far consist of english (US) keyboards writing spanish characters, while it may work for them, I use a fr_CA which already contains some accented characters (plus the letters on my keyboard *are* fr_CA).

Therefore, I tried activating the "Compose key position" and "Enable extra typographic characters", etc. but I find no way to write inverted ! and ? or ñ, etc. on my keyboard.

Anyone know how? Using the character map is getting tiresome. Thanks!

** **UPDATE** **

Setting the "Compose key position" to "**Right Ctrl**" makes the ñ work by pressing

> <kbd>AltChr</kbd> + <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> and then <kbd>n</kbd> = ñ

Now I'd love to be able to map custom chars to key combos :) I'd map something for the ¡ and ¿ chars (and other accented letters), etc.

** **UPDATE 2** **

As stated by [Pit](https://askubuntu.com/users/8642/pit), enabling the "Compose key position" works also with ¡ and ¿ by pressing

> <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (x2) = ¡
>
> Right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> (x2) = ¿
>
> <kbd>AltChr</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd> then <kbd>o</kbd> = ó
>
> etc

Solution accepted!

Comment: Your last edit should be an answer!

Comment: @Jorge Castro, indeed! However I accepted Pit's solution because of what he wrote in his solutions's comment. Granted, those comments should be in the answer instead, though. I updated the question with more details about the answer as I cannot modify Pit's answer :) ...for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System -> Preferences -> Keyboard` -> `Layouts` -> `Add...` -> `Spain Include dead tilde`

Works for me. I'm normally using ch_FR.

(You might want to print the keyboard layout.)

**Edit: I repost my comment which has actually solved the problem**

I got it! With I guess normal `fr_CA`, (if I add it by "By Language" with French in the first dropdown and Canada in the second).

You have to enable a `Compose key`:

You hold the `compose key` simultaneously with `Alt Gr` (left of space bar) and push `;` to get the `~` (it will not yet show up) then you hit `n` to get `ñ`. Sometimes it's a bit buggy and you have to hit the tripple key combo twice before hitting `n`.

For `¡` you use `compose key` + `shift` + `!` (1) and for `¿` it would be `compose key` + `shift` + `?` (6). Again sometimes you'll have to hit the tripple key combo twice .

Comment: if en_US can output the ñ without changing keyboard layout, why can't fr_CA? I'd hope not having to change/switch keyboard layout, if possible (if not, why?)

Comment: Every language has it's own letters and special characters, so it is not possible to include **every** possible character in one keyboard layout. Perhaps it is possible to include personal key-combinations in a standard keyboard layout.

Comment: I got it! With i guess normal `fr_CA`, (if i add it by "By Language" with `French` in the first dropdown and `Canada` in the second). You have to enable a `Compose key`. You hold the `compose key` simultaneously with `Alt Gr` (left of space bar) and push `;` to get the ~ ( it will not yet show up) then you hit `n` to get `ñ`. Sometimes it's a bit buggy and you have to hit the tripple key combo twice before hitting `n`. For `¡`you use `compose key` + `shift` + `!` (1) and for `¿` it would be `compose key` + `shift` + `?` (6). Again sometimes you'll have to hit the tripple key combo twice .

Comment: yes! That's what I wrote in my edit, but for the ¡ and ¿.. that I didn't know, and it works! thanks!

Comment: I saw your first edit after posting my last comment. I'm happy I could help you. This was actually quite useful for myself too.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Natty, the “Canda French (legacy)” layout has most of what you want; the "¿" is right alt + shift + "-"; right alt + "ç" gives you dead ascii tilde (so you go right alt + ç + n to get ñ). Not sure how to get ¡, however; depending on how often you use it, know that in GTK apps using the default input mechanism typing ctrl + shift + u followed by the unicode codepoint followed by whitespace will enter that unicode character, so ctrl+shift+u a1 space produces a “¡”.

[image]

However, more interesting is the “Canda Multilingual”, which seems (from me just looking at it for a little while) to have all the same main keys as the french legacy keyboard, but with a lot more right-alt variants:
[image]